# Migrate fonts from Ubuntu LTS to Amazon AMI Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, fonts, amazon-web-services

I want to migrate all the fonts from current server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to newest Amazon AMI Linux (AWS EC2).

I have copied all font files (respecting locations provided in `/etc/fonts/fonts.config`) and additionally all files in /etc/fonts/config.d

Unfortunatelly after regenerating fonts cache (`fc-cache -vr`) i get different results when listing them (`fc-list`). Even number of fonts does not match.

Does anybody know what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, simple things matter.

I was using `fontconfig` in version 2.8 on Amazon AMI, and 2.11 on Ubuntu server.

After installing 2.11 on Amazon AMI the fonts' list is being generated correctly.